# How to implement this in python : Check if a vertex exist, if not, create a new vertex

Tags: python, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I want to create a neptune db, and dump data to it. I download historical data from DynamoDB to S3, these files in csv format. The header in these csv like:

```
~id, someproperties:String, ~label
```

Then, I need to implement real-time streaming to this neptune db through lambda, in the lambda function, I will check if one vertex(or edges) exist or not, if exist, I will update the vertex(or edges), otherwise I creat a new one.
In python, my implementation like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Event').has(T.id, event['Id']).fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('Event').property(T.id, event['Id'])).property(Cardinality.single, 'State', event['State']).property('sourceData', event['sourceData']).next()
```

Here I have some questions:

1. In real-time streaming, I need to query if vertex with a id already
   there, so I need to query the nodes of historical data, so can
   `has(T.id, event['Id'])` do this? or should I just use
   `has(id, event['Id'])` or `has("id", event['Id'])` ?
2. I was using `g.V().has('Event', T.id, event['Id'])` instead of 
       `g.V().hasLabel('Event').has(T.id, event['Id'])`, but got error
       like `cannot local NeptuneGraphTraversal.has()`. Are these two
       queries same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the three bits of Gremlin you had a question about:

```
g.V().has(T.id, "some-id")
g.V().has(id, "some-id")
g.V().has("id", "some-id")
```

The first two will return you the same result as `id` is a member of `T` (as a point of style, Gremlin users typically statically import `id` so that it can be referenced that way for brevity). The last traversal is different from the first two because, as a `String` value it refers to a standard property key named "id". Generally speaking, TinkerPop would recommend that you not use a property key name like "id" or "label" as it can lead to mistakes and confusion with values of `T`.

As for the second part of your question revolving around:

```
g.V().has('Event', T.id, event['Id']) 
g.V().hasLabel('Event').has(T.id, event['Id'])
```

You can't pass `T.id` to the 3-ary form of `has()` as Kelvin points out as the step signature only allows a `String` in that second position. It also wouldn't make sense to allow `T` there because `T.label` is already accounted for by the first argument and `T.id` refers to the actual graph element identifier. If you know that value then you wouldn't bother specifying the `T.label` in the first place, as the `T.id` already uniquely identifies the element. You would just do `g.V(event['Id'])`.

Comment: I didn't think in 3-ary form the second parameter could be anything but a String key value. It fails for me with TinkerGraph also.

Comment: ugh....see, this is why you don't overload `T.id` with a property key called "id". just leads to all kind of misunderstanding. fixed my answer. thanks kelvin